# Multiple values for one Key in Swift Dictionary

Tags: swift

I was wondering what the possibilities are regarding using multiple value types in a dictionary in Swift.

For example If I have a Dictionary named cats, this Dict has a key of String "Bob". Now I want "Bob" to have 2 values, 1 Bool and 1 String. For example True and "Red"

```
var cat = [String: [Bool, String]]()
```

The above fails with

> "Generic struct 'Dictionary' requires that 'String.Type' conform to 'Hashable'.

I tried

```
var cat = [Hashable: [Bool, String]]()
```

But this provides error

> Generic struct 'Dictionary' requires that 'Hashable.Protocol' conform to 'Hashable'

I want for example:

```
var cat = ["Bob": [False, "Red"], "Albert": [True, "Black"]]
```

Is this possible if not what could be a good solution?

Edit:

I solved my problem using a struct however the suggestions using a Tuple also seemed to help me towards my resolution!

Thank you it's solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a bad error message. The real issue is that `[Bool, String]` isn't a valid type. There is no way to specify an array of fixed length with specific types in specific spots. Instead, use a tuple:

```
var cat1 = [String: (Bool, String)]()
var cat2: [String: (Bool, String)] = ["Bob": (false, "Red"), "Albert": (true, "Black")]
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is a misuse of dictionaries, types, or both. I would suggest you reconsider your entire approach. If you're going to be associating a name with a string and a bool, make a custom struct:

```
struct Person : Hashable {
    let name : String
    let favoriteColor : String
    let knowsSwift : Bool
}
```

Now you can store those in a Set and extract one by name, or you can make a Dictionary of Person keyed by name, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object

```
struct Item {
    let isAvailable: Bool
    let colour: String
}

var cat = [String: Item]

cat = ["Bob": Item(isAvailable: true, colour: "Red")]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tuple](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-tuple) is what you're looking for:

```
var cat = [String: (Bool, String)]()
```

or it would be better to do it like this:

```
var cat: [String: (Bool, String)] = [:]
```

You can also add label for tuple positions:

```
var cat: [String: (adult: Bool, color: String)] = [:]
```

---

For your second example

```
var cat = ["Bob": (false, "Red"), "Albert": (true, "Black")]
```

or

```
var cat: [String: (adult: Bool, color: String)] = ["Bob": (false, "Red"), "Albert": (true, "Black")]
```